# Asp.Net Core Linq how to perform a nested groupby with a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, group-by, many-to-many

I'm creating a KPI dashboard that displays the total income from orders. The business logic is that each item is linked to a type of event with a many to many relationship , and linked to a supplier type via a one to many relationship. And there are different suppliers which sell these items based on the supplier type. There is also a table that links suppliers to their order by using the orderItemId and supplierId. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- Get all orders that have been successfully fulfilled and get their order items.
- Get the supplier order items from the table I mentioned above using the order items.
- Once I have the supplier order items, I want to group them by the supplierId, and iem event type id so that I can display the items that each supplier sold of each event type.
- Supplier

  - Event Type

    - List of items
- Supplier

  - Event Type

    - List of items

The above is what I want to happen. I managed to group them by supplier id but I'm struggling to group them by eventTypeId because of the many to many relationship between the item and the event types.

Here are the models:

```
 public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        Favorites = new HashSet<Favorite>();
        ItemDetails = new HashSet<ItemDetail>();
        ItemEventTypes = new HashSet<ItemEventType>();
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
        SupplierItems = new HashSet<SupplierItem>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Column("isDeleted")]
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public int? EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfGuestsId { get; set; }
    public double? DaberniPrice { get; set; }
    public double? RegularPrice { get; set; }
    public int? Tax { get; set; }
    [Column("SupplierTypeID")]
    public int? SupplierTypeId { get; set; }
    [Column("SortID")]
    public int? SortId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public int? Min { get; set; }
    public int? Max { get; set; }
    public int? Increment { get; set; }
    public bool? IsShisha { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSoldByPackage { get; set; }
    [Column("ImageAR")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string ImageAr { get; set; }
    [Column("DescriptionAR")]
    public string DescriptionAr { get; set; }
    [Column("TitleAR")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string TitleAr { get; set; }
    public int? Capacity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Catrgory.Items))]
    public virtual Catrgory Category { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(NumberOfGuestsId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(NumberOfGuest.Items))]
    public virtual NumberOfGuest NumberOfGuests { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SupplierTypeId))]
    [InverseProperty("Items")]
    public virtual SupplierType SupplierType { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Favorite.Item))]
    public virtual ICollection<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ItemDetail.Item))]
    public virtual ICollection<ItemDetail> ItemDetails { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(ItemEventType.Item))]
    public virtual ICollection<ItemEventType> ItemEventTypes { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(OrderItem.Item))]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(SupplierItem.Item))]
    public virtual ICollection<SupplierItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }
}

public partial class ItemEventType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(EventTypeId))]
    [InverseProperty("ItemEventTypes")]
    public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemId))]
    [InverseProperty("ItemEventTypes")]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

 public partial class SupplierAssignedOrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("SupplierID")]
    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }
    [Column("ItemID")]
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(OrderItem.SupplierAssignedOrderItems))]
    public virtual OrderItem Item { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Status))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(OrderStatus.SupplierAssignedOrderItems))]
    public virtual OrderStatus StatusNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SupplierId))]
    [InverseProperty("SupplierAssignedOrderItems")]
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will more likely get a useful answer if you take a bit more time to provide a minimal reproducible example. (1) Trim your schema down to eliminate properties not relevant to the problem at hand - just the IDs and perhaps an object name here and there would be nice. (2) Provide some sample data to populate the the schema. (3) show us what your desired results for the given sample  (4) Show us the work you have done so far in an attempt to achieve these results. This will give us something to build on.

Comment: ASP.Net doesn't do groupby. The Entity Framework version used is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with EF Core,you could get orders and Supplier as follow :

DBcontext:

```
public class EFCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<EFCoreDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Item { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }  
   
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item");        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("Order");     

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>().HasKey(x => new { x.ItemId, x.OrderId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>().HasOne(x => x.Item).WithMany(x => x.OrderItems).HasForeignKey(x => x.ItemId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>().HasOne(x => x.Order).WithMany(x => x.OrderItems).HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>().ToTable("OrderItem");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasMany(x => x.Orders).WithOne(x => x.Supplier).HasForeignKey(x => x.SupplierId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().ToTable("Supplier");

        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierItem>().HasKey(x => new { x.ItemId, x.SupplierId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierItem>().HasOne(x => x.Item).WithMany(x => x.SupplierItems).HasForeignKey(x => x.ItemId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierItem>().HasOne(x => x.Supplier).WithMany(x => x.SupplierItems).HasForeignKey(x => x.SupplierId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierItem>().ToTable("SupplierItem");
    }
```

controller:

```
var orderlist = _context.Order.Include(p => p.OrderItems).ThenInclude(q => q.Item).ToList();
            
var supplierlist = _context.Supplier.Include(p => p.SupplierItems).ThenInclude(q => q.Item).ToList();
```

And I think it'll be better if you remove some properties from your itemclass and add them to SupplierItem class,such as the price property and Event Type property.

an item may have different prices if you buy from different supplies,also in different days. If the event type is used to describe the state of the trade ,it should be removed as well.

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
            
            SupplierItems = new List<SupplierItem>();
        }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }        
        public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }        
        public List<SupplierItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }
    }
public class Supplier
    {
        public Supplier()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
            SupplierItems = new List<SupplierItem>();            
        }
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public List<SupplierItem> SupplierItems { get; set; }
        
    }    
public class SupplierItem
    {
        
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        
        public double SupplierItemPrice { get; set; }       

    }
```

If you really want to group the supplier list by two properties
you could try:

```
var somesupplierslist = supplierlist.GroupBy(x => new { x.SupplierId, x.SupplierName }).ToList();
```